# fastapi Sub-dependencies cache value?

Tags: python, fastapi

[image]

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Body, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class ReqBody(BaseModel):
    name: str
    email: str

def format_body(body: ReqBody = Body()):
    body.email += "@xx.com"

@app.post("/")
async def post(f_body = Depends(format_body), body: ReqBody = Body()):
    print(body)
```

hello everyone I see in the document that multiple use of sub-dependencies will cache the return value. I understand that Body is also a dependency and has encountered some problems.I expect that body has been modified. What's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use `body = Body()` in your controller - instead, make your dependency do the work and return the result:

```py
async def body_with_email_extension(body: ReqBody = Body()):
    body.email += "@xx.com"
    return body

@app.post("/")
async def post(body = Depends(body_with_email_extension)):
    print(body)
```

That way caching won't matter, and the code reads more clearly, as it now indicates *what* preprocessing you're depending on, and what that preprocessing does.

Answer (score 0):

@MatsLindh

Thank you for your reply. In real use scenarios, body is organized by multiple functions. Each function is responsible for some data
For example, http body

```
{
  'p1_name': 'xxx'
  'p1_age': 'xxx'
  'p2_name': 'xxx'
  'p2_age': 'xxx'
  'p3_name': 'xxx'
  'p3_age': 'xxx'
}
parse_ function1(body = Body()):
# logic
parse_ function2(body = Body()):
# logic
parse_ function3(body = Body()):
# logic
```

If the body state cannot be shared, this will cause a parse_ function3-> parse_ function2 -> parse_ Function1 Does this look a bit confusing? I wonder if there is a better way to solve such problems.